# Refrigerator noise mysteriously stops when someone stands close to it

Tags: noise

So there is this rattling noise that a refrigerator makes from time to time. That wouldn't be weird, that's what refrigerators do.

What is spooky about this is that when you walk close to the refrigerator about 30 cm or 1 foot of distance, the noise stops. As soon as you move further back it starts again. If you move back again it stops and so on. This works with 100% consistency.

It seems to me that it has something to do with EM field, but what and how and why, answers to those are a complete mystery to me.

Does anyone here have any idea, what could be the source of the noise and how it could be potentially fixed? It sounds kind of unusual, not like the typical sounds it and other refrig. make.

To supply some information, it is a fridge with a freezer in the top part and there is a microwave resting on top of it. Next to it is television and espresso machine. (That probably isn't relevant at all, but who knows! Better to include information)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to electronics design.

Comment: There was some RF spirits question around....

Comment: "rattling" seems like a mechanical problem, like fan motor bearing, or fan fouling against ice buildup - can't think of any electrical cause of "rattling".

Comment: What kind of floor do you have ? If its a wood based floor then the weight of a person could tilt the refrigerator ever so slightly and stop/start the noise.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the weight of the person on the floor. Possibly deforming it so that all four feet of the refridgerator are "grounded". Either that or you're storing some chicken that is possessed by a poultrygeist.

Comment: I once quietened a rattling washing machine by putting a bag of groceries on it, so I think mechanical resonance is definitely at play here. Perhaps the person standing nearby acts like a 'mechanical dampener' connected to the fridge via the floor

Comment: You're right, the floor is the kind of plastic type, so it's deformable I've done some more experiments and indeed it appears to be caused by uneven support from the bottom. Thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that the floor is actually a little uneven (wood perhaps?) and by standing close it flattens out and the fridge no longer can shift between 3s of it's 4 legs.

Comment: That is the same thought I had!

Comment: I agree . most mechanical structures have a resonance Q of at least 10 even with motor vibr. dampers and evaporator grills on back or underneath tend to vibrate with motor are audible if slightest contact.. but then you may have the newest people sensing fridge ;)